# Text in UISearchBar doesn't highlight

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Here is an image of the issue:

[image]

As you can see the text is highlighted (select all) was pressed, however, as you can see the text isn't actually highlighted.

I don't think it matters but this search bar isn't searching local data it's using Algolia.

My class in implementing `UISearchBarDelegate` the search bar is created in code not interface builder and the only method implemented is `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` which I can include code for, but I don't think it's needed. Additionally, this VC is inside a navigation controller

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 135;
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge()
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a white selection color.

Comment: I looked over the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar but I don't see anything about selection color. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect comes from a white selection color. You can change the selection color by assigning a color to the property `tintColor` of `UISearchBar`, or over the appearance for all search bars:

```
UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
```